# Round decimal point with HTML5 output

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an html5 calculator that looks like

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber"<br>
    <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any"> +<br>
    <input name="b" id="b" type="number" step="any"> =<br>
    <output name="o" for="a b"></output><br>
</form>
```

And would like to round the results to 2 decimal points.

Comment: Hmm, `<output>` tag. Interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is another way to achieve what you are looking for, and will always show the decimal places regardless if they are 0 or not.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber).toFixed(2)"<br>
    <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any"> +<br>
    <input name="b" id="b" type="number" step="any"> =<br>
    <output name="o" for="a b"></output><br>
</form>​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/NRtwh/)**

Comment: Your answer is probably better and definitely simpler in this case. +1

Comment: @sachleen thanks, Im a bit conflicted though, because your answer is the defacto way to round a number to the nearest decimal place with JS :? so have a +1 as well :P

Comment: both work, but as Loktar mentioned below, toFixed holds the decimal at two places and works better for displaying $

Answer (score 2):

This will round to two decimal places.

```
Math.round(num * 100)/100
```

This is a more general version of it, rounds to a set number of places.

```
function roundNumber(num, places) {
    return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places);
}

roundNumber(24.2424, 2)
24.24
```

Comment: This is normally my go to method. Only thing the OP needs to take into consideration is this method will not show any decimal places if they are zero. So if hes just doing it for display purposes only, 5+5 is going to show 10, not 10.00