# format a number in HTML

Tags: html, format

I have a HTML formatted email and the data coming into the email consists of a number with too many zeros. Like 435.0000000000000. How can I add HTML formatting to reduce the decimal places of the number down to 2?

Comment: What did you try ? Please see [ask] and give a [mcve]

Comment: I have tried this: Requested Spend: <<EstCost/> step=".01"> <P> and it only outputs the entire string.   EstCost is my variable

Comment: pure html won't help you at this point. You need javascript code, something like 'toFixed()' js function.

Comment: As @Buzzinga suggests - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068050/round-decimal-point-with-html5-output) answer.

Comment: STUCK.... How I format this Requested Spend: <<EstCost/>.toFixed(2)> <P>